# Unexpected touch behavior in Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android, touchscreen

On my 2012 Nexus 7 running Android 4.4.4 and the latest version of Chrome, I've noticed that when I touch and hold links that are close to each other, it may not select the link I intend to select. Instead of activating the link at the center of the touch area (the behavior I expect), Chrome seems to select the link based on the entire area covered by my finger:

[image: Link selection in Chrome based on the entire touch area and not merely the center of the touch area]

Is this (counterintuitive) behavior normal? Can I configure Chrome to simply use the center of the touch area instead?

Answer (score 0):

Going by the unexpected touch behaviour you provide it seems that your multi-touch screen is not responding properly to your inputs for this you need to confirm it by doing a small and freely available  multi touch  test.

Download the [app](http://www.appbrain.com/app/multitouch-visible-test/com.batterypoweredgames.mtvistest) and check whether the touch is shown exactly where you selected. The two dots are drawn exactly where the phone reports you are touching.

or else you can simply do the following

1- Go to the developer options section in settings.

2- enable pointer location.

3- touch the screen as lightly as you can. you will notice a red number on the upper right corner of the screen named ""Prs:". this indicates the level of contact needed to register a touch.

4- do the same on different areas of the screen & remember try to touch the screen as lightly as you can (the goal here is to find the lower number that registers a touch)

If you see that at one point of the screen the screen is not responding according to your input then you need to get in contact with your Authorised service centre and report the issue.

Comment: I highly doubt this is the issue. I was using the pointer location dev tool to show the image shown here and the touchscreen is clearly working, This is a software issue (possibly by design, possibly a bug).

Comment: @DragonLord possible update will help resolve it.